# Member values on stack or heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

This could be a duplicate. But,I couldnt find one.

Doubt:

Let us suppose class A and class B.

If I do this.

```
A* aPtr = new A;  //This is an heap allocation
```

If I do this

```
B bObj; //This is stack allocatio
```

What if I have a class C, which has both A and B obj like this.

```
class C
{
   A aObj;
   B bObj;
};
```

and if the allocation of C is like this:

```
C *cptr = new C; //here memory allocation for cptr is heap. 
                 //But, what about aObj and bObj, which are not heap allocated?
```

Are both aObj and bObj allocated on heap, though they look like stack objects?

Comment: It is all a heap allocation.  The constructor of C will call the constructors of aObj and bObj.  If those constructors were to do something unique, like use a private allocator.  Some memory used by aObj or bObj may not come from the heap.  But that would be extremely rare.

Comment: It may help (or not) if you stop  thinking of them as "stack" vs. "heap" and start thinking of them as "automatic" vs "dynamic", because that is verbatim how they're described in the standards. If you want more in-depth answers to questions like this, that is a great place to look. C++11 3.7.3 describes *Automatic storage duration* in detail; C++ 3.7.4 likewise for *Dynamic storage duration*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally hate the word "heap" and "stack" when refereeing to C++ because the C++ standard does not enforce where the memory gets allocated. All the standard guarantees is when the memory will be freed.

Therefore, I prefer the names `Dynamic memory allocation` and `Automatic memory allocation` to distinguish between the two.

Automatic memory allocation will be deleted when either it goes out of scope or the object it lives in is deleted.

Dynamic memory allocation will be deleted when it is explicitly freed in the code.

Something like this `C *cptr = new C;` is allocated using the Dynamic memory allocation and will require to be deleted before the program ends or you will have undefined behavior.

Where as `B bObj;` will be allocated using the automatic memory and will be deleted when the object it lives in is deleted.

Comment: It isn't undefined behaviour to not delete dynamic memory. The standard doesn't appear to make any requirement that you ever delete pointers returned by `new`. Many programs rely on this behaviour for global objects.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y It is undefined behavior, but on a modern operating system you can expect the OS to clean up after you when the program shutdown. But C++ will not guarantee that.

Comment: Where in the standard does it says it is undefined? Note that unspecified, or implementation defined, is very much different from undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`aObj` and `bObj` are members of the `C` instance on the heap. So yes, `cpt->aObj` and `cpt->bObj` are on the heap.

If instead, you had

```
C c;
```

then `c.aObj` is on the stack and `c.bObj` is on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

In the declaration of class C,  the member A and B are just also declaration. With operator [new], the pointer cptr will be allocated in heap, and the members will also be in heap.